# Bring Safari to front

Tags: safari, xamarin.ios

I'd like to bring Safari to the front (switch to) but without using a URL, instead I'd like to see the "pages" view so the user can pick an already loaded page. Is this possible?

We open links in Safari and if the user returns to the app and selects the link again, I'd rather let them pick which Safari page to browse instead of opening a new one. I know that if the same URL is called it will open the correct page but the user may have navigated within the original site so the url no longer matches.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that its possible, i would use a UIWebView inside your app in order to get that experience you want, you can find the UIWebView apple docs here (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and also the equivalence of c# methods here (http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html) hope this helps

Alex

Comment: The problem with this situation is that we do not have control over the content, that is determined by the user. So, if a site does something like "new page" our webView just goes white. I don't know any way around that. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your app doesn’t get control of Safari’s UI. You might, however, be able to design your site so that it handles navigation via Javascript—AJAX and whatnot—so that the actual page URL doesn't change, and thus so that the page, re-opened from your app, brings up the existing Safari page. Of course that introduces further problems with your pages no longer being bookmarkable, but you might find that an acceptable tradeoff.